# Empty data frame from Date selection

Tags: r, date

I have a data frame with 3262 rows and 10 columns. One of the columns has date with format `YY-MM-DD`. I want to store all the rows with 10 different dates in a different data frame so I tried :

```
newdata= df[df$Date %in% as.Date(c('2011-08-05','2012-1-13','2012-03-2','2014-04-01')),]
```

but nothing. I thought it might need to specify again the format so I tried:

```
df$Date <- as.Date( as.character(df$Date), "%d-%m-%y")

newdata= df[df$Date %in% as.Date(c('2011-08-05','2012-1-13','2012-03-2','2014-04-01')),]
```

All I get is an empty data frame saying `no data available in table`. At which point I made the mistake (something stupid I guess)?

Comment: I can reproduce a working minimum example, so the problem seems to be in your conversion. have a look at the result of ``as.Date``, probably with ``head(df)`` or ``any(is.na(df$Date))``. This works well: ``Dates <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2016-01-01"), as.Date("2016-02-01"), by = "days"))``, ``Dates[Dates$Date %in% as.Date("2016-01-25"),]``

Comment: can you check class(df$Date), if it's factor or character, 

newdata= df[df$Date %in% as.Date(c('2011-08-05','2012-1-13','2012-03-2','2014-04-01')),]

should work.

If this class(df$Date) is Date, the following should work:

newdata= df[df$Date %in% as.Date(c('2011-08-05','2012-1-13','2012-03-2','2014-04-01')),]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an example:

```
set.seed(1)
df=data.frame(col1=seq(1,10),
    col2=seq(1,0),
    Date=as.Date(floor(runif(min=15550,max=17000,n=10)),origin="1970-01-01"))
> df
   col1 col2       Date
1     1    1 2013-08-17
2     2    0 2014-01-19
3     3    1 2014-11-06
4     4    0 2016-03-06
5     5    1 2013-05-17
6     6    0 2016-02-21
7     7    1 2016-04-28
8     8    0 2015-03-14
9     9    1 2015-01-27
10   10    0 2012-10-26
```

Using the same code you provided:

```
newdata= df[df$Date %in% as.Date(c('2013-08-17','2015-01-27')),]
```

Gives me

```
> newdata
  col1 col2       Date
1    1    1 2013-08-17
9    9    1 2015-01-27
```

Are you sure that `str(df$Date)` shows you really have a Date format?

```
> str(df$Date)

     Date[1:10], format: "2013-08-17" "2014-01-19" "2014-11-06" "2016-03-06" "2013-05-17" "2016-02-21" "2016-04-28" "2015-03-14" "2015-01-27" "2012-10-26"
```

Comment: Thank you all. It was factor and I checked this like @sandipan mentioned and now all your solutions work. Thank you!